# Как убрать каждую N отметку на оси графика?

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

Есть код для построения графика. Подскажите как удалить каждую N отметку на оси ОХ.

```
infile = open(filename, 'r')

numbers = []
names = []
for line in srez:
    words = line.split()
    number = float(words[1])
    numbers.append(number)       
    name = str(words[0])
    names.append(name)
month = range (0,n//2)

plt.xticks(month,names,rotation = 90,fontsize = 7 )

plt.plot(month, numbers) 
plt.grid(True)
#plt.savefig('005.png', dpi=200)
plt.show()
plt.close()
infile.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоит явно указать библиотеку, используемую для графиков. Для примера создайте самодостаточный пример (с искусственными данными), покажите что он (именно этот пример) выводит и опишите явно что вы хотели вместо этого получить (хоть руками засечки удалите/добавьте) [mcve]

Comment: Я Вас понял,спасибо,исправил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта: либо в целом уменьшить количество меток, либо руками передать нужные метки.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

data = range(100)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(data)
locator = MaxNLocator(prune='both', nbins=3)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(data)
ticks, _ = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(ticks[1:-1:2], ticks[1:-1:2])

plt.show()
```

Т.е. в вашем случае, можно сделать:

```
plt.xticks(month[::2],names[::2],rotation = 90,fontsize = 7 )
```

что оставит только каждую вторую метку.

Comment: Я Вас понял,спасибо,но это изменить его вид,а не просто уберет каждую Х  метку

Comment: Вид графика не должен меняться, вы же поменяете только метки. Единственное что может произойти, это то что у вас оси сместятся. Чтобы вернуть их на место, можно воспользоваться методами xlim и ylim.